How to access ACF option' sub-field outside of the option page?
My homepage has embedded an ACF option page, which included two feature banners.
From dump() of the large feature banner, I got this array (showing parts that are relevant to this q):
array:24 [
......
 "featureBanners" => array:2 [▼
    0 => {#3489 ▼
      +"url": "https://wordpress.test/2024/3/latest-drops"
      +"shop_url": "https://wordpress.test/shop/latest-drops"
    }
    1 => {#3488 ▼
      +"url": "https://wordpress.test/2024/3/sale"
      +"shop_url": "https://wordpress.test/shop/sale"
    }
  ]
  "bannerSetting" => {#3489 ▼
    +"url": "https://wordpress.test/2024/3/latest-drops"
    +"shop_url": "https://wordpress.test/shop/latest-drops"
......
]

I have added a "Shop Now" button on the url page.
When I'm on the url page and use dump(), there's no "featureBanners" and "bannerSetting" displayed on the array. I need to access the "shop_url" sub-field in order to link the button to the url.
On homepage, I've used get_feature_post_url function to get the shop_url sub-field
{% if bannerPost.id is defined %}
......
   {% set shopUrl = get_feature_post_url(bannerSetting.shop_url ?? '') %}
......
{% endif %}

Related twig functions in ArchiveHelperExtension.php:
public function getFunctions(): array
{
   return [
     ......
      new TwigFunction('editorial_feature_posts', [$this, 'getFeaturePosts']),
      new TwigFunction('get_feature_post_url', [$this, 'getFeaturePostUrl']),
    ......
   ]
}

The definition of get_feature_post_url:
public function getFeaturePostUrl(string $url, ?Post $post)
{
    $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    $locale = $request->getLocale();

    if (!($post instanceof Post) || !in_array($locale, ['hk', 'tw'] {
            return $url;
    }

    $postLocale = $this->postHelper->getPostLocale($post, $locale);

    return preg_replace(['/zh/', '/hk/', '/tw/'], $postLocale, $url, 1);
}

I was trying to access an ACF option's sub-field shop_url outside of the option page. Expected to see bannerSetting on the actual url page as well but could not see it and so unable to access the shop_url as well.
Sorry really spent hours thinking on this.
Please let me know what can I do to fix this?
Much appreciated!

@DarkBee Thanks! I've filled in the definition. May I know why it was treated as undefined? Added a fallback value in the edit as well.

"From dump() of the large feature banner" - Did you do dump(aVariable) or dump()?

@DarkBee I did dump(), let me go try dump(aVariable). Thanks!

No, that's fine. That means should that bannerSetting.shop_url should be defined. Try doing a {{ dump(bannerSetting.shop_url) }}. Futhermore what is the expected result?

Thanks @DarkBee! Yes using {{ dump(bannerSetting.shop_url) }} I got the right URL. But I want my user to click into the post (bannerSetting.url) and can still get redirected from the shop now button. But my post don't have this shop_url sub-field. So was expecting this sub-field can be passed to the post page from homepage.
